# How do I enable the "Universe" repository?

Tags: software-center, package-management, software-sources

How do I get to the Universe Repository in supported versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: Related: [“Unable to locate package” while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)

Comment: it showed me error on aws ububtu standard , but managed to fixed it ike this
    
- add-apt-repository universe
      - apt update
      - apt-get install -y curl jq python3-pydot graphviz

Answer (score 271):

If you want in one command and not use Software source ticking then in terminal put:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

On older versions of Ubuntu, you might have to use a full source line:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

To enable all Ubuntu software (`main universe restricted multiverse`) repositories use

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
```

you can add also `partner` repository with different link (see difference is ubuntu to canonical)

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Then update the package list:

```sh
sudo apt-get update
```

p.s.

`$(lsb_release -sc)` checks your Ubuntu version and puts its name in the source link. Since 12.04 is called `precise`, you can test in a terminal that `lsb_release -sc` gives `precise`. That adds the precise name of your Ubuntu release in Software sources. Wrong word and nothing will work.

For all differences in repositories read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: Just a note that you may have to run `sudo apt-get update` before you can install the package you wanted.

Comment: Debian doesn't always come with lsb_release installed, but if you have it you can use a similar syntax with their mirror URLs.

Comment: `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`

Answer (score 54):

First, open software center. Click on 'edit' and then 'software sources' to open the software sources window. Once that is open, check the box that says, "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)."

[image]

Now, all the universe packages should show up in software center just like all the other ones.

More information:

- [How do I enable the "Universe" repository from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78613/how-using-terminal-enable-universe-source-no-version-specified-so-it-auto-detec)

Comment: In my case ( on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) This option was already checked. So i have just unchecked it and then checked it again. Click on "revert" and then software cache will update. And then i was able to install stable chrome using ubuntu software installer with stable debian page. Thanks @user69469 :)) Strang!! isn't it?

Answer (score 40):

### Command Line Way of enabling  Ubuntu software Repositories For 12.10 and above:

#### To enable main repository,

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
```

#### To enable universe repository,

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

#### To enable multiverse repository,

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

#### To enable restricted repository,

```
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
```

**NOTE:**

After enabling the repositories, don't forget to update it.Run the below command to update the repositories,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: what's the difference between your answer and kangaroo's answer, yours seems shorter, and simpler.

Comment: Because my answer won't work for the versions below 12.10

Comment: Is there also a way to check them first? So you only enable them when they aren't enabled already... For scripting purposes.

Comment: If they are already enabled, you'll get a message saying that it is already available
```
$ sudo add-apt-repository main
'main' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
```

Answer (score 18):

Open dash and type `Software sources`

[image: type <code>software sources</code> in Dash]

then open software sources and click on the the universe repository .

[image: select "Community maintained Open Source Software (universe)"]

Close and reload cache

[image: reload cache]

Answer (score 1):

To use add-apt-repository, you will need the package software-properties-common:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Then you can use add-apt-repository to add the needed repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

Comment: This package is installed by default, so this answer doesn't really add anything new.

Comment: There is an earlier comment about the command being missing, and it was for me as well after creating a minimal bootstrap.